# Rational Application developer 9.0 and worklight studio 6.0 run android application Errors occurred during the build

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-rad

I try using Rational Application developer 9.0 and worklight studio 6.0 run android application. But have below

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'HelloTestHelloWorldAndroid'.
sun/security/x509/X500Name

Before see many answer is about JDK version is not mathch. I have download JDK 1.7 and install setting the JAVA_Home. And someone another method is change eclipse.ini setting. The RAD eclipse.ini is different with eflipse juno version. So i try many method unitl now the error is persists.

Answer (score 1):

I checked around on this and here is the info I got:

The issue is either you have the wrong JDK on the system or have the correct JDK but wrong JDK first in the classpath look-up.

A)  Make sure you just have one JDK on the system and it is 32-bit SUN JDK - since Android SDK depends on this JDK

B)  Find all other JDKs on the system and uninstall them

C)  Make sure you have JDK from Sun and not JRE.

Comment: if your Oracle/Sun JDK is installed after Eclipse started with IBM JDK, please clear $eclipse\configurations\org.eclipse.osgi folder to request eclipse to re-initialize plugin state with Sun JDK again.